# Prove that a regular $\phi : E \to E$ can be uniquely decomposed as a composition of self-adjoint map and a rotation(Unitary trick of Weyl)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, adjoint-operators

In the [book(archive.org)](https://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4684-9446-4) of *Linear Algebra* by Greub, at page 226 it is asked that:

Note: $E$ is a $n$-dimensional real vector space.

> Prove that a regular linear transformation $\phi$ of a Euclidean space
>   can be uniquely written in the form  $$\phi =  \sigma \circ \tau,$$
>   where $\sigma$ is a positive self-adjoint transformation and $\tau$ is
>   a rotation. Hint: Use problem 5 and 10.(This is essentlally the
>   unitary trick of Weyl.)

Question 5:

> A selfadjoint transformation $\phi$ is called positive, if $$(x,\phi(x))
>  \geq 0$$ for every $x\in E$. Given a positive selfadjoint
>   transformation $\phi$, prove that there exists exactly one positive selfadjoint transformation $\psi$ such that $\psi^2 = \phi $.

Question 10:

Note: $\bar \phi$ is the adjoint mapping of $\phi$, which is defined as
$$(x, \phi (y)) = (\bar \phi(x), y) \quad x,y \in E.$$

> Let $\phi$ be any linear transformation of an inner product space $E$.
>   Prove that $\phi \circ \bar \phi$ is a positive self-adjoint mapping.
>   Prove that $$(x, \phi \circ \bar \phi(x)) \geq 0 \quad x\not = 0$$
>   with equality only if $x \in ker(\phi)$

Even though the author gives some hints how to prove this result, I have stuck at this problem for, I guess, a month, and still couldn't figure out how to prove it. Then I have asked this to one of my assistants, but she couldn't figure out either, so my main question is that **how can we prove this result**, but any kind of help, some more hints, or general idea of the proof, *anykind*, is also very welcomed.

Note that, I have put a link of the book directly copied from archive.org, so you can check it out yourself also.

Comment: Are you able to prove Qs 5 & 10, or are you stuck on those too?

Comment: @JacobManaker Yeah, I couldn't prove those also.

Comment: You may want to add to the question that $\bar{\phi}$ is the Hermitian adjoint of $\phi$.  The conventional notation is $\phi^*$, and, although it is fairly clear from context, it's not nice to make a puzzled viewer have to click through ~200 pages of a book to figure that out.

Comment: @JacobManaker Thanks for pointing out, see my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a linear transformation is positive, any eigenvalue must be non-negative:

$$0\le (Ax,x)=(\lambda x,x)=\lambda (x,x)=\lambda ||x||^2$$

Section 8.9 in your book shows that a self-adjoint operator has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $e_j$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_j$. So if $A$ is positive and self adjoint and invertible, its effect on a vector $\sum v^je_j$ can be written

$$Av=A\sum v^je_j= \sum v^jAe_j=\sum v^j\lambda_j e_j$$

where the $\lambda_j$ are positive.

Given such an $A$, Consider the linear transformation $Bv=\sum v^j\sqrt{\lambda_j} e_j$. Then a straightforward computation shows that $B^2=BB=A$ (thus $B$ is a "square root" of A), and that B also is positive and self-adjoint and invertible.

$B$ is also the *unique* positive self-adjoint square root of $A$. To see this, note that since $B$ is positive and self-adjoint and invertible it also has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $f_j$ with positive eigenvalues $c_j$. Since $Af_j=BBf_j=Bc_jf_j=c_j^2f_j$, each $f_j$ is also an eigenvector of $A$ and the corresponding $c_j$ equals $\sqrt{\lambda_i}$ for some $i$. In other words, the effect of $B$ is to scalar multiply each $\lambda_j$ eigenspace of $A$ by $\sqrt{\lambda_j}$. This determines $B$ uniquely since the eigenspaces of $A$ span $E$.

Now we can use all of the above to prove the original claim. Given an invertible linear transformation $\phi$, consider $A=\phi\phi^T$. Then $A$ is positive and self adjoint: $$(x,Ax)=(x,\phi\phi^T x)=(\phi^T x, \phi^T x)=||\phi^T x||^2\ge0$$ $$(x,Ax)=(x,\phi\phi^T x)=(\phi^T x,\phi^T x)=(\phi\phi^T x,x)=(Ax,x)$$ and it is invertible, so it has a unique positive self-adjoint square root $B$ which is also invertible.

Now suppose $\phi=BU$ for some rotation $U$. Then we must have $U=B^{-1}\phi$. So we'll define U by this formula and prove it is a rotation, which is to say it preserves the inner product

$$(Uv,Uv)=(B^{-1}\phi v,B^{-1}\phi v)=(\phi^TB^{-1}B^{-1}\phi v,v)=(\phi^T A^{-1}\phi v,v)$$

$$=(\phi^T (\phi\phi^T)^{-1}\phi v,v)=(\phi^T (\phi^T)^{-1}\phi^{-1}\phi v,v)=(v,v)$$

So $U$ is a rotation. To prove uniqueness, suppose also that $\phi=CV$ for a positive self adjoint $C$ and a rotation $V$. Then

$$\phi\phi^T=CVV^TC=C^2$$

so that $C$ is also a positive self-adjoint square root of $\phi\phi^T$. But uniqueness of $B$ was proved above, so $C=B$. Then $V=C^{-1}\phi=B^{-1}\phi=U$, so the decomposition is unique.

Comment: Thank for your answer @juan, it is a quite clear answer.

Comment: BTW @onurcanbektas, the motivation for this theorem is that any non-zero complex number $z$ can be written uniquely as $bu$, where $b=\sqrt{z\bar{z}}=|z|$ is a non-negative real number and $u$ is a complex number of unit norm. Rotations are a linear transformation analogue of norm $1$ complex numbers ($u\bar{u}=1$), "self-adjoint" is an analogue of "real" ($\bar{r}=r$), and "positive self-adjoint" is an analogue of "positive real number" ($rz\bar{z}=r|z|^2\ge 0$). The decomposition $BU$ can be thought of as analogue of the decomposition $bu$.

Comment: The map $B=\sqrt{\phi\phi^T}$ in my answer is often written $|\phi|$. The unit complex numbers, real numbers, and positive real numbers are precisely the rotations, self-adjoint linear transformations, and (invertible) positive self-adjoint linear transformations of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: I did now know that, thanks for sharing @juan.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I don't see the connection to Weyl's unitary trick; I know this phenomenon by the name of [Polar Decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition).

#### For problem 5:

Note that there exists an orthonormal eigenbasis for $\phi$; this is proved earlier in the chapter.   Let the eigenbasis be $\{e_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda}$.   Now, let $f$ be a continuous function on some set containing the spectrum of $\phi$.   It might seem reasonable to define $f(\phi)$ to be the operator with identical eigenbasis, and eigenvalues $f(\phi)(e_{\lambda})=f(\lambda)e_{\lambda}$.

**Exercise**: This coincides with evaluation in the natural way if $f$ is a polynomial, or just analytic.

Back to the problem at hand: we want to solve $$\psi^2=\phi;$$ how would you solve this if the unknowns $\psi$ and $\phi$ were real numbers, not operators?  Can you apply the argument involving $f$ I sketched, above?

#### For problem 10:

For self-adjointness, note that self-adjointness is involutive and an antihomomorphism.   Then mess around with the givens.

For positivity, mess around with $(\bar{\phi}x, \bar{\phi}x)$.

#### For the main problem:

Problem 10 suggests looking at $\phi\circ\bar{\phi}$.   **If we know what $\sigma$ is and we know $\sigma$ is invertible**, then we immediately know $\tau$; namely, $$\tau=\phi\circ\sigma^{-1}$$  Now substitute into $\phi\circ\bar{\phi}$.   If you correctly use the two problems to construct $\sigma$, you should be able to get a cancellation and show that $\tau\circ\bar{\tau}=I$, i.e. $\tau$ is orthogonal.   Then you have enough degrees of freedom to make it *special* orthogonal (and thus a rotation).

But, of course, $\sigma$ is not guaranteed invertible from the two problems; they explicitly make you spend time working out what kernels are.   Think about what I just said: *they explicitly make you spend time working out what kernels are*.   Can you work out a direct-sum decomposition to fix the above argument?

#### A final remark:

The source by Brian Hall on the linked Wiki page is pretty good.   There, he uses my sketch for problem 5 more extensively.   Greub does *not* expect you to solve these problems by that route, but if you're interested, can you use logarithms and exponentials to obviate some of the difficulties above?

Comment: How is a spectrum of a linear transformation defined in your proof ?

Comment: I googled it, and it is defined as the set of eigenvalues of $\phi$ for finite dimensional case, but then $f(\phi)$ does not make sense.

Comment: By the way, spectrums are not mentioned in the book.