# Can any linear map, $\phi$, can be expressed a as $\phi = S + N - N^T,$ where $S$ is a self-adjoint and $N$ is a nilpotent map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, nilpotence, skew-mapping

Inspired from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875873/prove-square-matrix-can-be-written-as-a-sum-of-a-symmetric-and-skew-symmetric-m) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648523/prove-that-a-regular-phi-e-to-e-can-be-uniquely-decomposed-as-a-compositio) , I claim that

> Any linear map, $\phi$ on a real vector space $E$, can be written as a
>
> $$\phi = S + N - N^T,$$ where $S$ is a self-adjoint and $N$ is a
>   nilpotent map ($N^T$ denotes the adjoint of $N$, and its matrix is the transpose of the matrix of $N$)

Observe that, the map $$\psi = N - N^T$$ is a skew map. Moreover, given a skew, map we can always find a nilpotent map $N$ s.t the above equality holds.

In fact, we we take the entries of the matrix of $\psi$ above diagonal and form a new matrix with those entries, we get a nilpotent matrix, and the above equality holds.

As it has been proven that the linked question, we have

$$\phi = S + \psi,$$
hence we have 
$$\phi = S + N - N^T$$
QED.

### Question:

Is there anything wrong with this argument ? I mean I have never seen such a theorem, anywhere, and I want to make sure that the relation that I found is correct.

Comment: @user1551 please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim seems to be correct.
In real every matrix can be decomposed into symmetric and skew-symmetric part.

$A=1/2(A+A^T)+1/2(A-A^T)$.

And skew-symmetric part has $0$'s on diagonal. Then two parts of skew-symmetric part are certainly nilpotent. So for real matrices decomposition $A=\text{sym}(A)+N-N^T$ is always possible.